# How to add a button to freeze and resume the bouncing ball JAVA

Tags: java, jpanel

I want to add 2 buttons to the following code that will let me "FREEZE" and "START" the ball move as it bounces on the window. I've been trying to do this for the last hour but I cant figure this out. I did some work but it mostly crap, if anyone wants please let me know to post it(avoided it in order not to extend my coding). Anyone can help me with this?
Open to any suggestions. 
Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BallMoves extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    Color color = Color.red;
    int dia = 30;
    long delay = 40;
    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 1;
    private int dx = 3;
    private int dy = 7;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x,y,30,30);   // adds color to circle
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.drawOval(x,y,30,30);   // draws circle
    }



    public void run() {
        while(isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        if(x + dx < 0 || x + dia + dx > getWidth()) {
            dx *= -1;
            color = getColor();
        }
        if(y + dy < 0 || y + dia + dy > getHeight()) {
            dy *= -1;
            color = getColor();
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    private Color getColor() {
        int rval = (int)Math.floor(255);
        int gval = (int)Math.floor(0);
        int bval = (int)Math.floor(0);
        return new Color(rval, gval, bval);
    }

    private void start() {
        while(!isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BallMoves test = new BallMoves();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(test);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
        test.start();
    }
}
```

Update version

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BallMoves extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    Color color = Color.red;
    int dia = 30;
    long delay = 40;
    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 1;
    private int dx = 3;
    private int dy = 7;
    private boolean isRunning;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x,y,30,30);   // adds color to circle
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.drawOval(x,y,30,30);   // draws circle
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        if (isRunning) {
        if(x + dx < 0 || x + dia + dx > getWidth()) {
            dx *= -1;
            color = getColor();
        }
        if(y + dy < 0 || y + dia + dy > getHeight()) {
            dy *= -1;
            color = getColor();
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
    }

    private Color getColor() {
        int rval = (int)Math.floor(255);
        int gval = (int)Math.floor(0);
        int bval = (int)Math.floor(0);
        return new Color(rval, gval, bval);
    }

    private void start() {
        while(!isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final BallMoves test = new BallMoves();
            JFrame f = new JFrame();

            JButton start = new JButton("start");
            start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                test.isRunning = true;
            }
        });

            JButton stop = new JButton("stop");
            stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    test.isRunning = false;
                }
            });

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(start);
            panel.add(stop);

            f.add(panel, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            f.getContentPane().add(test);

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
            test.start();
        }

    });



}
}
```

Comment: We are not here to do your work. Tell us how are you trying to make this work and the specific problems you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a flag and switch it on button click.

```
private volatile boolean isRunning;

public void move() {
    if (isRunning) {
       // your existing code 
       ...
    }
}
```

on start button click

```
 isRunning = true;
```

on stop button click

```
 isRunning = false;
```

Comment: can you explain further?

Comment: any references I should check?

Comment: I have updated it in my code. Let me add it for you in frame also.

Comment: thanks I've been working on this for the last 3 hours can't figure it out I am new in java Jframe

Comment: The usual concept is to have the animation thread and the UI thread running concurrently. The communication point between the two threads, in this case, is the boolean 'isRunning' (which should be designated as volatile to assist in cross-thread communication). The animation thread consults 'isRunning' before proceeding with the iteration of the animation cycle. The UI thread signals to the animation thread whether to pause/stop or go via this boolean.

Comment: I got the last part but I didn't quite get the post with the flags on top

Comment: updated the question, all the current code is below the *updated Version*, getting errors on the action listener

Comment: You are using `ActionEventt` it must be `ActionEvent`. double `tt`.

Comment: the error i get is on the start.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  as well as the stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  and on both @Override

Comment: Find `ActionEventt` and replace with `ActionEvent` by the way I have updated in your code itself.

Comment: **The problem is with imports. try `import java.awt.event.*;` instead of `import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;`**